# Hot to submit a form that was loaded in modal?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

After loading a form into modal-body into twitter bootstrap, how do I submit this form using modal primary button?

I don't want to set #id because this primary button have to submit every form loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will go using a selector like `$('#idofmodal .modal-body form').submit()`

Obviously you must change this selector according to your markup (or post the markup here so I can change it according to it)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try making the input type="submit" inside the form that's inside the modal.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax in doing that.

```
$(".yourBtnClass").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
         url: "save.php",
         data: { data: $("[name=oftextbox]").val()
                   },
         success: function(r){
         $(".productsList").html(r);
    },
    dataType: "html"
    });
    return false;
});
```

check this link http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/